# Copy files from 1 library to other - site content & structure vs Workflow

Tags: workflow

I can use **"Site Content and Structure"** to move bunch of selected files from one library to another in matter of seconds. For example, about 1 minute to copy all the files with metadata to target library.

However, Copy Item method in workflow takes hours. Any idea why? Is there any way to use same method that "Site Content and Structure" uses from Workflow?

Please suggest as this is becoming a real painful issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does it take hours for the copy to be completedone or for the workflow to actually start running?

You may want to add an entry to the workflow history before and after the copy operation to check that.